# Is it possible to work with a German D Visa in France?

Tags: germany, france

let say that you have a German working visa type D that you got it 3 months Ago and now you want to relocate and start working in France.

Comment: All non-EU citizens wanting to work in France need both a visa that allows them to live and work in France, as well as a work permit that gives them the right to employment in France.

Comment: @Traveller such documents do not tend to be issued separately.

Answer (score 2):

No, a German visa (any kind) is not a valid work permit in France, and does not entitled you to work in France. You need to get a French residence permit or work visa.